# Generating Duration from Time Values

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to find a way via `moment.js` to convert two time values, which are coming in as as start and stop times, expressed in hours and minutes as string values, like this: start: `1:12`, and stop: `2:10`, or in the afternoon, start: `14:23`, and stop: `15:22` and generate a duration in milliseconds from this. I have tried the following, but it gives me a `NaN` result:

Just to clarify, I am receiving the data in string format. See below for what that looks like:

```
const startValue = "1:12";
const stopValue = "2:10"; // for a duration of 58 minutes

const msDuration = moment(stopValue).format('HH:mm').valueOf() - moment(startValue).format('HH:mm').valueOf();
```

I assume the issue here is that my `startValue` and `stopValue` need to be converted to a different format first, since they are currently string values? So, how can I convert a string value of "1:12" to be something `moment` can use?

Comment: don't format as a string.

Comment: You are parsing in a wrong format. Check out what [moment parses](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).

Comment: @DanielA.White, lol, I don't have a choice. That's how the data's coming to me.

Comment: @DanielA.White `moment.js` can actually format strings but not that kind of strings. ISOStrings for example are supported

Comment: So, @MrJami, then what is the correct format? That's the root of my question. Something like this? `moment(new Date(stopTime).format('HH:mm').valueOf())`? Or do I need to pass in some semblance of a date as well?

Comment: is it ok for you to use vanilla JS?

Comment: That depends on how verbose it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Invalid parsing

   Your time inputs are not in a standard format that Moment recognizes, so you'll have to use a formatted parse to explain your times to it.
2. `format`ting as string before of calling
   `valueOf`.

   `.format()` converts your Moment object to a string, and strings can't be subtracted. To solve this, you can just drop the `.format()` call. Instead, you can also use `.diff()`, that will compute the difference for you.

So, you can use either of these:

```
const msDuration = moment(stopValue, "H:mm").valueOf() - moment(startValue, "H:mm").valueOf()
```

```
const msDuration = moment(stopValue, "H:mm") - moment(startValue, "H:mm") // Subtracting will implicitly call .valueOf()
```

```
const msDuration = moment(stopValue, "H:mm").diff(moment(startValue, "H:mm"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the succinct answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments above, I recognize that you are receiving the times as a response in the following format: "HH:mm".

If the actual Date doesn't really matter, then you can convert it like this ([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j52au0z4/)):

```
const startValue = "1:12";
const stopValue = "2:10"; // for a duration of 58 minutes
const start = { hour: startValue.split(":")[0], minute: startValue.split(":")[0] }
const stop = { hour: stopValue .split(":")[0], minute: stopValue .split(":")[0] }

const msDuration = moment().hours(stop.hour).minutes(stop.minute).valueOf() - moment().hours(start.hour).minutes(start.minute).valueOf(); //you might get 1 ms less. so jest set also ms to 0
const msDurationA = moment().hours(stop.hour).minutes(stop.minute).milliseconds(0).valueOf() - moment().hours(start.hour).minutes(start.minute).milliseconds(0).valueOf();
```

So basically you are taking the current date and mutate the hours and minutes, so you can work with moment.Js.

Although my question is, why do you necessary need moment? you can also do it in native JS:

```js
const startValue = "1:12";
const stopValue = "2:10"; // for a duration of 58 minutes

const start = { hour: +startValue.split(":")[0], minute: +startValue.split(":")[1] };
const stop = { hour: +stopValue.split(":")[0], minute: +stopValue.split(":")[1] };

const msDuration = (stop.hour * 3600000 + stop.minute * 60000) - (start.hour * 3600000 + start.minute * 60000);

console.log("msDuartion: ", msDuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JS:

```
function getMilliSecs(text) {
  const spl = text.split(":");
  return parseInt(spl[0])*60*60*1000 + parseInt(spl[1])*60*1000; 
}

function getMilliSecsDuration(start, stop) {
  return getMilliSecs(stop) - getMilliSecs(start);
}
```